# Angular2 - Reactive forms radio button value as object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of radio buttons on my component that are simple `yes` and `no` values. It uses `text` as the label and an `id` for its value.

I am trying to assign an object as its value so that when I submit my form, I can get access to both the `value` and `text`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" ng-value="{value:0, text:'No'}"> No
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" ng-value="{value:1, text:'Yes'}"> Yes
</label>
```

When I try this, it fails my reactiveForms validation as being a required field. How can I assign this object where the validation will pass when one of them is selected?

Comment: `ng-value` is from angularjs - use `value`

Comment: @Kai - My value comes through as such when using `value` submitting the form: `changeType:"{value:2, text:'Yes'}"` <- treats it as a string

Comment: The syntax for Angular 4 is `[ngValue]="{....}"`

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - `Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.`

Comment: Oh you can't use ngValue on input. Sorry. You're using reactive forms so the value is stored in the form control for "changeType"

Comment: @ThinkingMedia - So does this mean it can or can't be assigned manually via attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't see the component code, not really sure about the form part. But I was able to get object value from radio button selection using just `value`.

**UPDATE**: Since object needs to be passed, it's better to create them in the component and use `[value]` to bind the objects and pass them to the form. I have added couple of extra lines in `html` to show `value` and `text` are accessible.

```
<form class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="submit(addForm.value)" [formGroup]="addForm">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" [value]="radioItems0"> No
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" formControlName="changeType" [value]="radioItems1"> Yes
  </label>
  <p></p>
   <button md-raised-button  type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<p>Form values:</p> 
<p>{{ addForm.value | json }}</p>

<p>Selected value: {{ addForm.value.changeType.value }}</p>
<p>Selected text: {{ addForm.value.changeType.text }}</p>
```

component.ts:

```
export class InputFormExample {

  radioItems0 = { value: "0", text: "No"}
  radioItems1 = { value: "1", text: "Yes"}

  addForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.addForm = this.fb.group({
      changeType: {}
    });
  }

  submit(form){
    alert(JSON.stringify(form));
  }
}
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/IdOAU9?p=preview)

Hope this resolves your problem :)

Comment: hmm, It looks like the value is a string though? For example, I can't do `form.changeType.text` to access the text value of the object.

Comment: I see what you mean. Will get back to you :)

Comment: One quick question - Can I still add validators to this input? I originally had `changeType: ['', Validators.required],` but not too sure how to do it with your example using an object.

Comment: You can still do the same, `changeType: [{}, Validators.required]`, make sure you have imported `Validators`, `import {Validators} from '@angular/forms';`. I have added that to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-value` will not work on input element. Try to use change event as

`<input type="radio" formControlName="changeType"  (change)="radioButtonSelect($event) value=0>No`

And in event handler

`radioButtonSelect(event){
     var text=event.target.value?'No':'Yes';
     this.selectedType={value:event.target.value, text:text};
}`